# How to compare old files with new files and display correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, compare

I have a **problem**...

I wrote a program which checks the current beats (music from my friend) I have already, then downloads the newest from his google drive and finally displays any changes that happened such as File Name, Modify Time and File Size.

Now it works partly - if a file was renamed or a file in the middle of the folder (like track 5 of 10, not the last file) was removed, or a middle folder (like folder 4 of 5, not the last folder) was removed, it gets confused and it mistakes other tracks as the removed/renamed track.

Same with the folder. If folder 4 was removed, it mistakes folder 5 for folder 4 and simply says it got renamed and **all the files inside** also...

I hope I explained my problem well. Here is the code

```
import gdown, time, os, math, dictdiffer, re
from   colorama import *
from   art      import *
from   datetime import datetime

# fix file details
# fix comparison

#initializing colorama for the "clear" variable being able to clear the screen
init()

# clear var to clear screen
clear      = "\033[2J\033[1;1f"


# Beats By Brendlef link
url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WjQxT1s_oW8AXsvmO4rAcL2b5h4fmW95?usp=sharing"

# Function to convert size to displayable information
def convert_size(size_bytes):
   if size_bytes == 0:
       return "0B"
   size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
   i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
   p = math.pow(1024, i)
   s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
   return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])

# Function to get info about beats in program folder, compare and deliver report
def get_info(mode):
    folder_main_list  = []
    folder_size_list  = []
    folder_mtime_list = []
    folder_ctime_list = []
    file_main_list    = []
    file_size_list    = []
    done              = False
    #accessing files and folders for information
    for x, y, z in os.walk(os.getcwd()): # x = main folder | y = subfolders | z = files
        # avoid getting info about git folder
        if "git" in str(x):
            continue
        folder_size = 0
        for f in z:
                fp = os.path.join(x, f)
                # skip if it is symbolic link
                if not os.path.islink(fp):
                    folder_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
        folder = str(os.path.basename(x))             #  get main folder name, last accessed time, last modified time, creation time and size in bytes
        tprint(folder, font="cyber")
        print("Last modified: "+datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")) # MAIN FOLDER
        print("Created      : "+datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(x)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S"))
        print("Folder Size  : "+str(convert_size(folder_size)))
        folder_main_list.append(str(x))
        folder_size_list.append(str(convert_size(folder_size)))
        folder_mtime_list.append(str(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")))
        folder_ctime_list.append(str(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(x)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")))
        print("-Folders in "+folder+":")
        if not y:
            print(" |NO FOLDERS IN "+folder+"!")
        else:
            for i in y:
                print(" |"+i)                         #  get sub  folder name, last accessed time, last modified time, creation time and size in bytes
                print("Last modified: "+datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(i)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")) # SUB FOLDERS
                print("Created      : "+datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(i)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S"))
                #print("Folder Size  : "+str(os.path.getsize(i))+" Bytes")                                                      incorrect value
                #print("Folder Size  : "+str(sum([os.path.getsize(i) for i in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(i)]))+" Bytes") also wrong?
        print("-Files   in "+folder+":")
        if not z:
            print(" |-NO FILES IN "+folder+"!")
        else:
            for i in z:
                try:
                    print(" |-"+i)                        #  get file name, last accessed time, last modified time, creation time and size in bytes
                    beat = str(x)+"\\"+str(i)                    
                    print("Last modified: "+datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.abspath(beat))).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")) # FILES
                    print("Created      : "+datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(os.path.abspath(beat))).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S"))
                    print("File   Size  : "+str(convert_size(os.path.getsize(beat)))+" Bytes")  
                    file_main_list.append(str(i))
                    file_size_list.append(str(convert_size(os.path.getsize(beat))))
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    print(" |-"+str(i)+" not found.")
                    continue
                #
                #  DOESNT WORK DUE TO WHITE SPACE IN MY USERNAME1
    # COMPARING OLD BEATS WITH NEW BEATS
    if mode == 1:
        print("Checking current beats...") #CHECK OLD BEATS
        time.sleep(1)
        global intel_folder, intel_file
        fields = ["Folder Name", "Folder Size",  "Folder Modify Time", "Folder Creation Time"]
        values = [folder_main_list,folder_size_list, folder_mtime_list, folder_ctime_list]
        intel_folder = dict(zip(fields,values))
        fields = ["File Name", "File Size"]
        values = [file_main_list,file_size_list]
        intel_file = dict(zip(fields,values))

    elif mode == 2:
        print("Checking new beats...") #CHECK NEW BEATS
        time.sleep(1)
        fields = ["Folder Name", "Folder Size",  "Folder Modify Time", "Folder Creation Time"]
        values = [folder_main_list,folder_size_list, folder_mtime_list, folder_ctime_list]
        intel2_folder = dict(zip(fields,values))
        fields = ["File Name", "File Size"]
        values = [file_main_list,file_size_list]
        intel2_file = dict(zip(fields,values))
        # COMPARING BEATS
        print("COMPARING...") # COMPARE OLD BEATS WITH NEW BEATS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        time.sleep(1)
        if intel_folder == intel2_folder:
            print("NO CHANGES!")
        else:
            print("SOMETHING CHANGED!")
            time.sleep(1)
            ##### DISPLAYING CHANGES ## DISPLAYING CHANGES ## DISPLAYING CHANGES #####
            for foldif in list(dictdiffer.diff(intel_folder, intel2_folder)):
                
                if   foldif[0] == "change":  # listing all folders that changed either in size or by modify time

                    # if Folder Size in info1[0] or if Modify Time
                    info1 = foldif[1]
                    info2 = foldif[2]

                    if "Folder Size" in info1[0]:

                        print("Size of Folder '"+str(info1[1])+"' changed from "+os.path.basename(str(info2[0]))+" to "+os.path.basename(str(info2[1]))+".")

                        if done == False:
                            done = True
                            for fildif in list(dictdiffer.diff(intel_file,intel2_file)):
                        
                                if   fildif[0] == "change" and "File Size" in fildif[1]: # listing all files that changed in size
                                    print("File "+str(fildif[2])+" changed in Size.")
                                    #print(str(fildif[3]))
                                elif fildif[0] == "remove" and "File Name" in fildif[1]: # listing all files that got removed
                                    removed = re.findall("'([^']*)'",str(fildif[2]))
                                    if len(removed) > 1:
                                        removed = str(removed).replace("[","").replace("]","")
                                        print("Files "+str(removed)+" were removed.")
                                    else:
                                        removed = str(removed).replace("[","").replace("]","")
                                        print("File " +str(removed)+" was removed.")
                    elif "Modify Time" in info1[0]:

                        print("Modify Time of Folder '"+str(info1[1])+"' changed from "+os.path.basename(str(info2[0]))+" to "+os.path.basename(str(info2[1]))+".")

                        for fildif in list(dictdiffer.diff(intel_file,intel2_file)):
                            
                            if fildif[0] == "change" and "File Name" in fildif[1]:
                                info = fildif[2]
                                print("File "+str(info[0])+" was renamed to "+str(info[1]+"."))

                elif  foldif[0] == "remove" and "Folder Creation Time" in foldif[1]: # checking if a Folder got removed in its entirety
                    info = str(foldif[2]).replace("(","").replace(")","")
                    info = info.replace("[","").replace("'","").replace("]","")
                    info = info.split(",") # splits still too much
                    dt   = str(info[1])+str(info[2])+str(info[3])
                    print("Folder '"+str(info[0])+"' was removed. It's recorded Creation Date is"+dt+".")

                    for dif in list(dictdiffer.diff(intel_file,intel2_file)): # listing all files removed due to folder remove        (NEED TO GO THROUGH EACH FOLDER AND ITS FILES)
                        fildif = dif
                        if fildif[0] == "remove" and "File Name" in fildif[1]:
                            print("File "+str(fildif[2])+" was removed.")

                
                    

#################################################################################### PROGRAM START ####################################################################################

#getting intel about current beats
get_info(1)

# DOWNLOADING BEATS BY BRENDLEF
print(clear)
print("DOWNLOADING...")
#gdown.download_folder(url, quiet=True)                       # DOWNLOADING BEATS, NOT NECESSARY FOR EACH TEST
print(clear)
input("DONE!!!")
time.sleep(1)

#getting intel about new beats and comparing with old ones
get_info(2)
```

**Thanks in advance!**

PS: Im new in asking questions here, so if there was too few or too much information, please tell me and I'll edit.

Thanks again!

Comment: next time put ``` in separated lines.

Comment: normally I would use tools like [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) instead of Python. It uses program `diff` to compare content of two files and to compare folders. Python has also standard module `diff` but I don't know if it can compare folders.

Comment: But how can I use Meld in python ? It has to be used by python...

Comment: I said `"instead of python"`. And I also said `"It uses program diff"` and `"Python has also standard module diff"`. See standard module [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html). BTW: I mentioned `Meld` because in `Meld` you can see how `diff` compares files - and you can see if `diff` compares in way which you need.